# MVC 3 \ form submit button not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Submit Button is not working in FORM page. I have read many solutions for the same question, but not able to rectify the problem. Can somebody please point out the error or suggest change...??

**abc.cshtml**

```
     @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ABC", "Queries", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post",  UpdateTargetId = "content", LoadingElementId = "mask" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form- data", id = "intake_form", **@class** = "inline-form clear_both" }))
    {


     <div class="form_row">
        <div class="form_col1">
            <label class="QueryPageHeadings">
                Title*</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form_col2" style="z-index: 24; position: relative;" id="queryTitle_div">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ABC.QueryTitle, new { @class = "text QueryFormTextBox" })
            <br />
            <div style="float: left">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ABC.QueryTitle)
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
   <div class="form_row">
        <div class="form_col1">
            <label class="QueryPageHeadings">
                Specific Notes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form_col2" style="z-index: 21; position: relative;" id="specific_note_div">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ABC.SpecificNotes, new { @class = "text QueryFormTextBox", style = "resize:none;height:160px;" })
            <br />
            <div style="float: left">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ABC.SpecificNotes)</div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_row">
        <div class="form_col1">
            <label class="QueryPageHeadings">
                Supporting Document
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form_col2">
            <div style="width:100%;float:left;">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ABC.SupportDocument, new { @Id = "lblFileName", @readonly = "readonly" })
            </div>
            <div style="width:100%;float:left;">
            <button id='btnUploadPopup' type="button" style="float:left;" onclick="javascript:OpenFileUpload();">
                Upload Files</button>
                </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form_row form_footer">                          
        <p class="indent">
                <input class="secondary button float_right" value="Submit" type="submit" name="button" />                                 
        </p>
    </div>
     }
```

**Controller.cs**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ABC(ABCViewModel model, string button)
    {

            String errorMessage = "";
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
            {
                errorMessage = errorMessage + " Fields can not be empty.";
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
            {
                Session["errorMessage"] = errorMessage;
                IABC data = new ABCViewModel();

                data.ABC.QueryTitle = model.ABC.QueryTitle;
                data.ABC.SpecificNotes = model.ABC.SpecificNotes;
                data.ABC.SupportDocument = model.ABC.SupportDocument;

                TempData["isEdit"] = false;
                return View("ABC", data);
            }
            else
            {
                Session["errorMessage"] = "";
                Session.Remove("errorMessage");
            }


            Session["fileName"] = null;
            return View();

    }
```

Comment: try setting the method to `public ActionResult ABC(ABCViewModel model)`

Comment: Show us how you bind your model. I suspect `ABCViewModel` is only a part of the actual model.

Answer (score 0):

try to decorate with action method with the httppost attribute

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ABC(ABCViewModel model, string button)
{
   //your code
}
```

and change the button type to 'submit'

```
<button type="submit">....</button>
```

Comment: it wont..u need to create two action methods. one without the attribute and return to the View. Then create another ActionResult with the [HttpPost] attribute. try it.

Comment: I have created two action methods one is Get(without attributes) and second is Post(with Attributes).Above mentioned method is POST. Get is working fine but post is not.
When i click on submit button then it should call Post method, but its not. Any suggestions?

Comment: ya GET will work when ur dom is loading. POST will work when u try to post something to the server. plz try to make the button type to 'submit' and giv it a try again.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the required java scripts since you are doing an AJAX post. Add the following in your `_Layout.chtml` file.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also you need to decorate your controller method with `[HttpPost]` attribute.

PS: If you do not need asynchronous posing, just use `Html.BeginForm` instead of `Ajax.BeginForm`.

Comment: Why you need the `button` parameter on your action method? Remove it and try.

Comment: @model Project.ViewModel.ABCViewModel

@{  
    Project.Models.ABCModel ABC = Model.ABC;
    Project.Models.ABCModel QueryTitle = Model.ABC;

    Project.Models.RegisterModel registerModel = (Project.Models.RegisterModel)Session["userDetails"];
    if (registerModel == null)
    {
        registerModel = (Project.Models.RegisterModel)Session["GuestUser"];
    }
  
 }

Comment: If posible, try changing your binding to `Project.Models.ABCModel` and return `data.ABC` from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I've copy-pasted your code "AS-IS" and it works for me. Almost :) (I've changed '`**@class**`' to '`@class`' because of compiler error).

Try to repeat it on the empty project. Maybe you have changed something?